# Equicontinuity or mean equicontinuity?

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, automata, equicontinuity

Can someone provide some examples to illustrate the difference between equicontinuity and mean equicontinuity?
Can someone provide a concrete example that is mean equicontinuous  but not equicontinuous?
Thank you

Definitions:

A dynamical system (X,T) is called equicontinuous if for every $ε>0$ there is a $δ>0$ such that whenever x, y ∈ X with d(x, y) < δ, $d(T^n(x),T^n(y))<ε$ for n = 0,1,2,...

A dynamical system
(X,T) is called mean equicontinuous if for every ε > 0, there exists a δ > 0 such that
whenever x, y ∈ X with d(x, y) < δ,

$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}d(T^n(x),T^n(y))<ε$.

Comment: Maybe if you could provide the definition you're using of both terms, we could help you understand what the difference between them is.

Comment: [Maybe we can use the definitions at this link](https://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/de/webfm_send/271) .